# Binary Search function returning None value in python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-search

Below is the code which I used for binary search in python using recursion. I have not used `num == l[mid]` since this is being handled by function calling this binarySearch. I just have to return the last item of list being left while splitting it.

```
def binarySearch(l,num):
    length = len(l)
    
    if length==1:
        print(l)
        return l

    if length % 2 == 0:
        mid = (length//2) - 1
    else:
        mid = length//2
        
    if num < l[mid]:
        binarySearch(l[mid+1:],num)
    else:
        binarySearch(l[0:mid+1],num)
```

`print(l)` prints the correct value which I want to return but `return l` gives me `None` instead of `l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if num < l[mid]: binarySearch(l[mid+1:],num)` doesn't return anything: it calls `binarySearch` and discards its return value. Thus, `None` is returned implicitly. You should actually return the values you want to be returned:

```
if num < l[mid]:
    return binarySearch(l[mid+1:],num)
else:
    return binarySearch(l[0:mid+1],num)
```

Here, `return binarySearch(...)` means "return whatever the call to `binarySearch` returned".